# vuetify reset css dependencies between my coomponent and surrounding non-vuetify app

Tags: vuetify.js

I am creating a vue component styled with vuetify which will be embedded in another page with different styles and they conflict. Specifically the outer page did a default setting of `flex-direction: column;` which lead to some funny sizing effects and `flex-direction` was not among the first options I thought would conflict so I spent a bit too much time on figuring it out.
Also I read on https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset/ that

> The Vuetify style reset is applied globally and affects default
> elements such as button and input. This also includes anything located
> outside of the v-app component.

which means there may be side effects I don't know about my component introduces which is bad.

So even though I solved the problem at hand by setting `flex-direction:row;` I feel this is a bad solution as ther outer part may have side effects on my stuff and vice versa - maybe not now but in case of any change - which will be hard to find.

Is there some decent way to prevent that to eliminate both dependencies? Can't believe it but all i found was some rather options including webpack reconfigurations for sass overwrites etc.

Would an option be creating a web component from my component or would that not solve the css dependency issues (my guess is no)?

Thanks
Tom